# A question about usage of kernel API method kstrtol()

Tags: api, memory, linux-kernel, allocation

```
int kstrtol (   const char * s,
    unsigned int base,
    long * res);
```

Can someone advise me on whether I need to allocate memory for `long * res` before invoking this kernel API method? I couldn't find a clear answer online.

TIA

Vinod

Comment: `res` is output parameter, so yes, you need to allocate memory for it before the call to given function. Actually, with given signature it is impossible to `kstrtol` function to allocate the memory for you: would it allocate memory, it should return the address of allocation, but `res`, as output parameter, cannot accommodate an address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the res should point a allocated memory， for example:
long value;
const char *buf;
.... ....
kstrtol(buf, 10, &value);